# Не работает AJAX + Javascript код

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

При клике по ссылке

```
<a href="javascript: add2(123);"></a>
```

нужно скрыть этот div

```
<div style="position: relative; display: table; border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;" id="123">

</div>
```

check.js:

```
function add2(id) {

  var o=document.getElementById(id);

        $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(o),
        success: function(data) {
                        o.style.display='none';
                }
        });

      }
```

Не работает.

Спасибо, исправил, скрипт рабочий.

Comment: Вызываете функцию add2basket через вызов add2?

Comment: Соберите больше сведений. Что выдает консоль браузера, нет ли там ошибок? Вызывается ли вообще функция add2(...)? Проверьте это, вставив в начало функции add2 вывод в консоль console.log("да, вот я вызвалась"). В общем учитесь делать простейшее тестирование кода хотя бы.

Comment: Проверил, функция вызывается. Пишет такую ошибку:
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4e jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4Vc jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4Vc jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4Vc jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4Vc jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4Vc jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4m.param jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4m.extend.ajax jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4add2 check.js:11(anonymous function)

Comment: Ну, ответ Вы сами нашли, ошибка косвенно на это указывала, я только добавлю пояснение.

--------

В документации по JQuery Ajax сказано: по умолчанию, данные, переданные в параметр data в качестве объекта(с технической точки зрения, что-либо, кроме строки), будут обработаны и преобразованы в строку запроса, для соответствия типу данных по умолчанию — «application/x-www-form-urlencoded». Если необходимо отослать документ DOM или другие специфические данные, то установите опцию processData в false.

--------

Соответственно последняя ошибка возникала из-за неправильно переданных данных в data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Согласно

   > XMLHttpRequest is subject to the
   > browser's same-origin policy: for
   > security reasons, requests will only
   > succeed if they are made to the same
   > server that served the original web
   > page.

   AJAX запросы можно производить
   только на тот домен, с которого была
   загружена сама страница, использующая
   XMLHTTP.

   Следовательно `url: 'http://ya.ru',`
   попадает под эти ограничения.
2. При клике будет вызвана функция **add2**, однако далее Вы упоминаете о совсем другой функции **add2basket**.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил, но безрезультатно...
[code]
function add2(id) {
   
  var o=document.getElementById(id);

    $.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: o,
     success: function(data) {
     o.style.display='none';
   }
    });

  }
[/code]

Comment: Пожалуйста, взгляните
http://jsfiddle.net/erbolking/bkhuh0ah/1/

Comment: Спасибо, помогли, проблема была в $(o)